# Partition string in python and get all the value before colon

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have to get all the values before the last colon(:) i.e. `client:user:username:type` from the following string:

Input: `client:user:username:type:1234567`
Output: `client:user:username:type`

I know I can split by `:` and then iterate and append all the tokens before `:`.

But is there a better pythonic way to achieve this?

Comment: i dont understand - data.split(":")[:-2] - using split is just as pythonic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just find the index of last `:` and then extract the rest of string base on that

```
string="client:user:username:type:1234567"
index = string[::-1].index(':')
new_string = string[:len(string)-index-1]
print(new_string)
```

output

```
client:user:username:type
```

as suggested by @muzzletov, you can use `str.rindex` and then do string slicing

```
 new_string = string[:string.rindex(':')]
```

Comment: why not just use rindex?

Comment: @muzzletov didn't know about that, thanks will update